# Script printing Blob works on one hosting site, not on another

Tags: php

I've a script that prints images (Blobs from mysql DB). It works fine on Godaddy but when I move it to a UK hosting company it fails to print the image - prints the alt text instead (everything else works fine). GD is PHP 5.3 and the UK company is PHP 5.2. Both mysql DBs are 5. I have checked that the scripts are the same, correct data is in the DB etc.
I am at a loss as to where to look now.

The script is called with

```
echo "<img src = 'printimage1.php?recipetableID=$recipetableID'  alt='Picture does not display.'>";
```

and the printimage1.php script looks like

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/jpg");
$recipetableID=$_GET['recipetableID'];
include("connect.inc");
$connection = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password)
   or die ("couldn't connect to server");
$db = mysql_select_db($database,$connection)
   or die ("Couldn't select database");  
$query = "SELECT * FROM RecipeTable WHERE recipetableID = '$recipetableID'";   
$result = mysql_query($query)
   or die ("Couldn't execute query.");
   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
   {

        echo $row['Picture1content'];
   }
?>
```

Any suggestions appreciated.
John.

Comment: Use Firebug to see what printimage1.php prints. Or enable error reporting and access it directly. There certainly is some error there.

Comment: One more thing. Heard of `mysql_real_escape_string()` ?

Comment: Did you try loading `printimage1.php?recipetableID=enterAValidIdHere` itself in a separate window? Also, you might wnt to read some suggestion in [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4607943/).

Comment: Did you try loading printimage1.php?recipetableID=enterAValidIdHere itself in a separate window? I did and the image displays properly,